# Using numpy where to return an element in the same row but different column

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I am trying to use `np.where` to swap one element for another, in the same row (but different column).

Here is what I have so far:

```
arr = np.random.random_integers(0,10,size=(10,10))
split = np.random.random_integers(0,10,size=arr[1,:].shape)
newloc = np.random.random_integers(0,10,size=arr[1,:].shape)
arr2 = np.where(arr>split,arr[0,newloc],arr)
```

My problem is that 0 in arr[0,newloc] means that it always pulls from row 0 off arr. But I want something like "same_row" if that makes sense.

Comment: `newloc` is an array, what do intend to do here: `arr[0,newloc]`?

Comment: sorry mistake, should be ```arr[0,newloc[same_col_asarr]]``` I just don't know how to do it. My goal is basically if: arr>split, return a different element in the same row as arr, the location of which is held in newloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `arr[:, newloc]`. This will allow you to index `arr`'s second axis (i.e. the columns) with `newloc`'s values.

```
np.where(arr > split, arr[:, newloc], arr)
```

Here is an example with two rows:

```
>> arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2,10))
>> split = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=arr.shape[1])
>> newloc = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=arr.shape[1])

>> arr
array([[2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 4, 6, 5, 1, 9],
       [9, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 6, 2, 5]])

>> split
array([5, 7, 3, 5, 1, 6, 0, 8, 8, 6])

>> newloc
array([1, 7, 0, 5, 0, 7, 3, 6, 4, 8])

>> np.where(arr > split, 1, 0) # mask
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

>> np.where(arr > split, arr[:, newloc], -1)
array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0, -1, -1,  1],
       [ 2, -1,  9, -1,  9, -1,  3, -1, -1, -1]])
```

There, you can check if the columns are being replaced correctly.

---

I have used [`np.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) in the above snippet since [`np.random.random_integers`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html) is deprecated.